# PHP - How to handle same class in php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, class, plugins, wordpress-plugin-creation

Consider we have an SDK that will be included in wordpress with other plugins like freemius. So we have a class in our SDK.

```
class prefix__SdkClass
{

}
```

So suppose this SDK will be included in 2 plugins. There will be a fatal error because of the same classes in both plugins. So i will include some sort of versioning in my SDK so that when the SDK is installed in both plugins the SDK with the latest version should be used?

Answer (score 0):

The [Wordpress Best Practices](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/best-practices/) recommends using either prefixes or namespaces to avoid such collisions. Also, keep in mind that the user may use different versions of your two plugins. If one plugin uses an outdated SDK and the other one has the newer SDK which removed funtions of the old SDK, as soon as you force using the newest SDK may break the older plugin.

In your case of using the same SDK in two different plugins, I would go for:

**plugin 1**

```
<?php
class prefix1_SdkClass
{

}
```

**plugin 2**

```
<?php
class prefix2_SdkClass
{

}
```

or using [PHP namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php):

**plugin 1**

```
<?php
namespace Plugin1;
class prefix_SdkClass
{

}
```

**plugin 2**

```
<?php
namespace Plugin2;
class prefix_SdkClass
{

}
```